# docker-compose down without flag -v delete my named volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose

all my data lost when i use docker-compose down. I don't use  flag -v

I start container with

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Add some data to mongo.

Then I run docker-compose down without `-v` , and when i next time run docker-compose up, all my data is lost?

Does Docker deletes my volume?

But when I just stopped the mongo container with docker-compose stop and re-run the container, the data is still there.

My docker-compose file.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/usr/mongo-db/data

volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

Comment: other than it not supposed to do that, as you probably know yourself, we can probably not tell you much. You could try to include more info to really reproduce the problem. What commands do you run exactly? Whats the output of docker compose down? What is the output of docker volume ls?

Comment: Fixed.I just needed to change the path of the volumes to 
mongo-db:/data/db